# How do I get rid of the top border on this table header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 and have a table with 2 headers (only 1 header will be shown at one time). Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GQVK/)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="view_1"><th>Header 1</th></tr>
        <tr class="view_2"><th>Header 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="view_1"><td>View 1</td></tr>
        <tr class="view_2"><td>View 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

The initial view has .view_1 hidden and .view_2 shown. However, there's a slight top border on the header. This border disappears when you hide .view_2 and show .view_1. How do I hide that top border when .view_2 is shown?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post a working example with your CSS/JS etc. Try jsFiddle or CodePen for that.

Comment: @ralph.m He has already done that :)

Comment: @kristen : small suggestion, you could also try minimizing your jquery code in single line like this `$('.view_1, .view_2').toggle();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style that sets that gray border is the `.table th, .table td` in `bootstrap-combined.min.css:192`, so you should change the CSS in the fiddle for:

```
.table th, .table td { border:1px solid #333;}
```

That'll allow you to change the border's style. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4GQVK/2/)'s your fiddle with the modified CSS.

If you don't want the top border to be shown you need to add:

```
.table th { border-top: none; }
```

Comment: My brain must be butter right now. Thanks for the answer and for putting up w/ such a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below css, to get rid of the top border

CSS:

```css
table thead tr th,table th{border-top:0px;}
```

Include the bootstrap css first and then include your custom css, then only default bootstrap css will be overridden with your css.

Comment: Unless you want to cater to serious structural errors in the HTML, what you have there is exactly the same as just `th{border-top:0px;}`. A `th` is always in a `tr`; a `thead` is always in a `table` etc.